# Как написать функцию, которая возвращает строку или объект

Tags: java

```
public MyClass find(String name)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if(variable[i].equals(name))
        {
             return variable[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Ничего не найдено");
    return ?;
 }
```

Теперь сам вопрос:  Я хочу получить объект `variable[i]` при нахождении, иначе получить строку `"ничего не найдено"`. Можно просто ее вывести, но тогда все равно надо что-то возвращать. Что надо поставить вместо `?`, чтобы не было ошибки?

Comment: Ну, `public String find`?

Comment: variable[i] - объект класса myClass, при нахождении следует возвращать именно объект

Comment: Тогда зачем вам возвращать строку? Почему не null какой-нибудь?

Comment: Хорошо, можно вывести строку, "ничего не найдено"? Но что тогда надо возвращать? null?

Comment: или такое вообще невозможно?

Comment: Возвращать несколько разных типов наверняка можно, но это сильное переусложение кода и бесполезное замусоривание интерфейса метода. Если уж метод возвращает myClass, то пусть возвращает null, когда объект не найден

Comment: Спасибо, как вам благодарность отправить?

Comment: @МишаКотор нажми на его ник, в его профиле посмотри его ответы, и плюсани, если так хочешь отблагодарить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно переписать так

```
public Object find(String name) {
  return Arrays.stream(variable)
               .filter(o -> o.getName().equals(name))
               .findAny()
               .orElse("Ничего не найдено");
}
```

Comment: То есть возвращать можно просто любой класс, использую при этом Object?

Comment: Да, имменно так.